# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath .. reason: image not found

Tags: ios, xcode

I am running into the above mentioned error on Xcode 10.2.1 and iOS 11 when adding my custom framework to an existing project.
I tried all the options mentioned in the previous questions asked related to this same error.
Always Embed Swift Binaries is set to yes, cleaned, removed derive data, reinstalled the certs.
Would anyone be able to help with this?

Comment: How is it added? Carthage? Pods? Manually?

Comment: Manually @Larme

Answer (score 0):

You need to also add your framework as Embedded Binary. Go to your target, select "General" tab and "Embedded Binaries" there.

Most of the times, you are using Apple (iOS) provided frameworks, that come as part of iOS and there is no need to do anything else, but define you're using them. That's the "Linked Framework and Libraries" part. When you use your own framework however, you need to embed it as part of your application and also add it to "Embed Binaries".

[image]

Comment: I have it added to both the embedded binaries and the Linked Frameworks and Libraries.

Comment: Is the framework file in the folder (or a subfolder) of your project? You can also try to archive the project, then open the archive in finder and get deeper in the archive inside the `.app` file. There should be a subfolder `Frameworks`. Verify that your framework is there.

Comment: I see the framework added in the Frameworks folder. I tried creating an empty Framework and just added it but that fails too with the same error.

Comment: This is really strange and should not happen. You can try removing the dependency so the app can start and then print the environment variables of the process (including the above mentioned `rpath`) and see if that helps in any way. But I'm out of ideas here :/  I did have a strange situation some years ago when I was trying to name a framework with the same name as existing but not publicly exposed framework like `UserKit` but the error there was it loaded it but failed to find my methods inside.